# CheckBox is Already Checked But Textbox isnt enabled

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I have Used A function like CheckBox Checked Enable Textbox, It is working fine but On clicking edit button in grid view row  A pop up appears with all row columns in edit mode but this check box isn't checked and textbox is not enabled

I have used web method to get all the rows of grid row 
and used a prop

[webmethod]
$('<%=chk.clientid%>').prop('checked', var.hel) this is checking the checkbox
but how to enable the text box

$('<%=txt.clientid').val(var.txt); this should enable on row only if check box checked

any ideas??

help ??

Answer (score 0):

A search in bing gave me this code sample

```
function EnableTxt() {
    document.getElementById( '<%=txt.ClientID%>' ).disabled = 'false';
  }
```

Comment: But I have already used a function like text box enable when check box clicked its working fine normally , but when i click in grid row it isn't working

Comment: you may have to add a class to your input , <input type='textbox' class='selector' /> in order to select each row. using an ID selector in jquery will only find the first element. Does this help you?

Comment: i have to try this